# Calling pthread_create inside a member function?

Tags: c++, pthreads, x11

I created a widget.h file containing the declartions of `pthread_function` and I wanted to call it in a member function `destroyWidget` of that class Widget in widget.cpp. but always shows an error. I'll show the .cpp and .h file.

widget.h file

```
class Widget
{
public:
Widget();
void createWidget(int x,int y,int w,int h);
void showWidget();
int wid;
pthread_t thread;
int *incomingval,id;
void join();
Window win;
XEvent evt;
private:
void* destroyWidget(void* ptr);
Display *disp;
int screenNumber;
unsigned long white;
unsigned long black;
long eventMask;
GC gc;
int tbit;
int *incoming,val;
};
```

now the widget.cpp

```
Widget::Widget()
{
disp=XOpenDisplay( NULL );
screenNumber=DefaultScreen(disp);
white=WhitePixel(disp,screenNumber);
black=BlackPixel(disp,screenNumber);
eventMask=StructureNotifyMask;
tbit=0;
}

void Widget::createWidget(int x,int y,int w,int h)
{
wid=w;
win= XCreateSimpleWindow(disp,DefaultRootWindow(disp),x,y,w,h,1,white,black);
}

void Widget::showWidget()
{
XMapWindow(disp,win);
XFlush(disp);
gc=XCreateGC(disp,win,0,NULL);
XSetForeground(disp,gc,white);
XDrawLine(disp,win,gc,wid-10,0,wid,10);
XDrawLine(disp,win,gc,wid-10,10,wid,0);
//calling the thread function
pthread_create( &thread, NULL, destroyWidget, this);
}

void Widget::join()
{
pthread_join( thread, NULL);
}
void* Widget::destroyWidget(void* ptr)
{
Widget* mw = static_cast(ptr);
eventMask=ButtonPressMask|ButtonReleaseMask;
XSelectInput(disp,win,eventMask);
do{
printf("id= %d",id);
XNextEvent(disp,&evt);
}while(evt.type!=ButtonRelease);
XDestroyWindow(disp,win);
XCloseDisplay(disp);
return NULL;
}
```

now the main.cpp file

```
#include "widget.h"
#include
int main()
{
Widget* w=new Widget();
Widget* n=new Widget();
n->createWidget(20,20,150,150);
w->createWidget(50,50,250,250);
n->showWidget();
w->showWidget();
n->join();
w->join();
return 0;
}
```

the error is

```
widget.cpp: In member function ‘void Widget::showWidget()’:
widget.cpp:44:51: error: argument of type ‘void* (Widget::)(void*)’ does not match ‘void* (*)(void*)’
```

Comment: Indendation really does a lot to make your code readable. I highly recommend using it in the future. Even just a couple of spaces would be chill.

Comment: You should **NOT** use a member function **Not even** a static one. Read here for the correct solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352280/pthread-create-error-in-c/6352434#6352434

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `pthread_create` is a C-style function; you need to give it a pointer-to-function.  `Widget::destroyWidget()` is a pointer-to-*member*-function.  (Remember that non-static member functions always have an implied `this` argument, which `pthread_create` doesn't know how to provide.)

See the answers to this question for some possible solutions: [pthread function from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class).

Comment: I tried using static , but this gives a error on variables used in that whole function

Comment: @user: Did you try the other idea?  i.e. adding a `static` helper function which in turn calls the member-function?

Comment: @Oli: Nope, help me with it if u can.

Comment: A static member function is not sufficient.  The function must be `extern "C"`, and any language linkage on member functions is ignored.

Comment: @James: Perhaps you should raise that concern in the comments for the answer to that question?

Comment: @Oli Is there any point of raising concerns about an answer that appeared a year or more ago?  (Honest question: I don't really know yet how this forum works.)  Anyway, while the standard is quite clear about this, several (but not all) compilers ignore it, so you can often compile your code anyway, only to have it not work with a different compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Like Oli said you can't use a member function when a C-style function expects a "normal" function pointer. However, what you can do is make a separate function that calls back your destroyWidget() method.

Like so:

```
void* start_routine(void* arg)
{
    Widget* widget = static_cast<Widget* >(arg);

    widget->destroyWidget();

    return NULL;
}

void Widget::showWidget()
{
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &start_routine, this);
}

void Widget::destroyWidget()
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Sorry! There was a typo in start_routine it's fixed now.

Comment: widget.cpp: In member function ‘void Widget::showWidget()’:
widget.cpp:34:33: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&Widget::start_routine’
widget.cpp:34:52: error: cannot convert ‘void* (Widget::*)(void*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’

Comment: Is start_routine a static method of the Widget class? If it is try making it a "flat" function (taking it out of the class Widget) which should make your code compile and run. I've ripped this example straight out of a working codebase so it should work.

Comment: The correct call is `pthread_create(&thread, NULL, start_routine, this);` (no ampersand to take a function pointer).

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to `pthread_create` has the signature (in C++):

```
extern "C" void* (*pointerToFunction)( void* );
```

You're trying to pass it the address of a member function:

```
void* (Widget::*pointerToMemberFunction)( void* );
```

The signatures are incompatible: the second requires an object on which
to call it, and is not `extern "C"`.

The simplest way of handling this is to use `boost::thread`, with all
it's functional object support.  Otherwise, you can define something
like the following:

```
struct AbstractTask
{
    virtual ~AbstractTask() {}
    virtual void* run() = 0;
};

template<typename T, void* (T::*ptr)()>
class Task
{
    T* myObject;
public:
    Task( T* object ) : myObject( object ) {}
    virtual void* run()
    {
        return (myObject->*ptr)();
    }
};

extern "C" void* taskRunner( void* arg )
{
    std::auto_ptr<AbstractTask> p( static_cast<AbstractTask*>( arg ) );
    return p->run();
}

pthread_t taskStarter( AbstractTask* obj )
{
    pthread_t result;
    pthread_create( &result, NULL, &taskRunner, obj );
    return result;
}
```

To start a thread, you then call:

```
thread = taskStarter( new Task<Widget, &Widget::destroyWidget>( this ) );
```

(This is from memory, from an earlier project, so there might be some
typos in it, but you get the idea.  And you probably want to add some
error handling in `taskStarter`.)

Comment: Cant understand this procedure, can you explain it with reference to my program. I badly need it.

Comment: @user796094 The idea is that what you pass to `pthread_create` is a pointer to a function which casts its argument to a pointer to an interface, and calls a function in it.  Then you derive from the interface to do whatever you want; in this case, to make things simpler, there is a template to create the derived class, so you don't have to write it each time.  And the actual function passed to `pthread_create` will destruct the object you've created; since polymorphism is involved, and lifetime doesn't follow scope, you `new` it.